# Does this function f(x) have an inverse?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $f(x) = x$ , Does the inverse of $f$, $f^{–1}$ exist?
 According to the definition,  $f^{–1}= y$. But as it doesn't make sense I am going to assume it doesn't?

Comment: The function inverse is itself. $f(x) =f^{-1}(x)$

Comment: What definition are you using, how does it come up with $f^{-1}(x)=y,$ and why do you think this doesn't make sense?

Comment: Would it be okay to state f -1(x) = x or f -1(x) = y?

Answer (score 1):

This is the identity function. The inverse of the identity is itself. Hence, if $f(x)=x$, then $f^{-1}(y)=y$.

Answer (score 0):

The inverse is itself
f(x) is y=x
so even if you switch y and x, it's still y=x
Also the graphs of inverses are symmetrical over the y=x line so if your function is that line then the inverse is itself

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, the functions are symmetrical. Taking the inverse of $f(x)$ will still yield x. To learn more in depth about why this holds, check the link below.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function